# How do I disable network / wifi for guest account in OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, wifi, guest

I have an OS X machine (Mavericks) that I want to use as a public machine. For this reason I have activated the guest account. However, I can't figure out how to disable the ability for the guest user to connect to Wifi networks (like open networks around). That is, how do I remove or block the ability for guest user to access network settings / enable WiFi?

Answer (score 3):

Go to System Preferences → Network, select your Wi-Fi service and click Advanced….
Enable Require administrator authorization to: Change networks.

[image]

This will then require the username and password of an administrator on the computer to change wireless network, however this does not prevent an Ethernet connection from overriding the Wi-Fi connection should the Ethernet service have a higher priority (click the gear at the bottom of the service list, then Set Service Order…).